# Why does the Antonov 225 needs 6 crew members?

Tags: airliner, crew, airplane, antonov-225

Why does the Antonov 225 need 6 flight deck crew? What are they called and what do they do?

Comment: On [this](http://englishrussia.com/2014/03/23/how-does-the-largest-plane-work-facts-and-story-about-an-255/) site it says that it featured service personnel so I can assume 3 pilots and 3 service men but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Have a look at this website, it is amazing. Pass slowly through the pictures, some are active photos.   https://thepointsguy.com/news/photo-tour-antonov-an-225-largest-aircraft/

Comment: It needs 6 to fly and a lot more to carry on load/unload for sure. I witnessed one landing once and it's impressive by its size, dwarfing 747 all around but how gently was the final approach/landing, like a feather before touchdown

Comment: @jean when I say crew I mean like then people who are operating the plane. For example: pilots, navigator, radio operator, flight engineer, etc

Comment: @LeonardTan if you wish to be more specific, you can call them flight deck crew.

Comment: @AEhere so should I edit my questions?

Comment: @LeonardTan up to you, I don't think its needed, but you seem to have become aware of all the different people who fall under the crew moniker. I was just suggesting a way to disambiguate.

Comment: @AEhere Okay I am going to change it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A quick search points to the following being part of the crew

- **Pilot**
- **Co-pilot**
- **2x Flight engineers:** one [on the engine controls](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Antonov-Airlines-Antonov-Design-Bureau/Antonov-An-225-Mriya/2176944/L?qsp=eJxtjrEOgkAQRP9laxoFNaGTxlILfmCzN%2BoFhMveJnoh/LsHGiu7yXubmZ1IxsHwsjYFUE0RrHKnggIrPyLVE7FXUb5aw9HL52yz3R2KnzhhgP5XVJdVVRbUIT1Hdbkv70kXvOWJOKo1KSPHhqMIgsF9%2BVkddFGIsn5zW7pzgF7WTOU%2Bc%2Bdj6HntgLHvaZ7fVNxFuQ%3D%3D); I am not sure of the purpose of the second one but a good guess is hydraulic and electric system monitoring, based on his proximity to the circuit breaker panel [(source, scroll down for a 3D photograph of the flight deck)](https://thepointsguy.com/news/photo-tour-antonov-an-225-largest-aircraft/).
- **Navigator:** due to the age of the type and the amount of non-standard routes it flies.
- **Radio operator:** same reason as above.

The crew could likely be reduced after a modernization of the cockpit, without upgrading any other hardware like the engines, but the re-certification costs probably outweigh the benefits in this case, for a fleet size of 1.

Mostly sourced from this thread: [discussion on Airliners.net about the An-225 crew duties](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=762899), which also includes good images with annoyingly restrictive copyrights.

Comment: Wouldn't there also be a third pilot on long flights?

Comment: @MartijnVissers Not necessarily, the fully-loaded range is not huge, the amount of ferry flights the type has to do is limited (its not an airliner), it has much more leeway when it comes to flight scheduling and the regulations for chartered cargo flights might not be as demanding with respect to relief crews (this might be worth its own question, though). If absolutely necessary, accommodations can be made, not unlike regular airliners having ferry tanks installed in the cabin on occasion.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks ;-)

Comment: AEhere, thanks for the answer. But I would like to ask why do they need 2 flight engineers?

Comment: @LeonardTan I suspect the workload of monitoring 6 engines was considered excessive for a single crewman.

Comment: @MartijnVissers Upon further reading it seems there are further cabins available in the airplane for the loadmaster and other crew, both in the tail and near the flight deck, so for an exceptionally long ferry, a relief flight crew could bunk down with them.

Comment: AEhere, but on this picture it said that there is two pilots and four flight engineers: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dTR9hv93VIRTYfP8k7Hbv6iSzZmPCPl_

Comment: @LeonardTan looking closely it does seem that most engine instruments are available at the station directly behind the co-pilot. I cannot discern what are the  instruments at the station to the right of the engine gauges, but judging by the proximity of the circuit breaker panels, an educated guess would gravitate towards electrical or hydraulic system controls.

Comment: @LeonardTan also, please consider waiting 24 hours before accepting this answer, there might be more knowledgeable people who might be dissuaded from posting by the check mark.

Comment: Things are a bit simpler: An-225 inherited its crew arrangement from An-124, which was designed in the late 70s/early 80s. This is a military cargo airplane, and air forces have a different understanding of 'crew optimisation' and requirements. Separation of the navigator and radio operator roles was traditional; but I'm not sure about the role of the 2nd FE. He may be (or double as) loadmaster. Nothing to do with 6 engines at any rate. I had a chance to ask the pilots many years back, but I didn't...

Comment: @zeus indeed, that's why I edited it the engine speculation, as clearly the second FE is seated too far from their gauges. I don't think they double as loadmaster, since the aircraft supposedly carries its own ramp crew in berthing outside the flight deck, but that is just my speculation. Do you have a source on the crew commonality with the 124? I would like to read more about that.

Comment: I could probably find it, but no, not right now. This is considered 'general knowledge' though, from knowing the 225's development history. It is essentially a stretched and specialised version of 124, never meant for mass production. Their cockpits are very similar as well.